# Simple JS tree data structure representation

Tags: javascript, user-interface, treeview, client-side

I need to build a simple UI for representing a JSON data structure that follows a model similar to:

```
{ 
    person1 {
        name: 'Dan',
        address: {
            work: '9523 Pinehurst',
            home: '1234 foobar way'
        }
    },
    person2 {
        name: 'Paul',
        address: {
            work: '5432 Loop Street',
            home: '432 linux drive'
        }
    }
}
```

I need to support dynamic adding and deleting of categories, and dragging / droppping categories, such as moving the work address from person1 to person2. Any suggestions?

I tried using a dojo tree control but it got way too complex for what I'm trying to accomplish. This is just an entirely client-side demo application. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the dynatree. It is a plugn of JQuery for support dynamic treeview in javascript. Very simple your use.

[Dynatree](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/)

Hope this helps